# how to create dynamic setImageResource

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I replace something like:

```
when (content[position].ImageSrc) {
            1 ->  holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_1)
            2 ->  holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_2)
            3 ->  holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_3)

            else -> { 
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_x)
            }
        }
```

more elegant so something like:

```
var a = "image_"
var b = content[position].ImageSrc
var c = a + b
holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.c)
```

The first code is working but way to laborious, the second one isn't.
Thx:)

Comment: The "R" values are integers that are "autogenerated" from the R(esources), you cannot do it that way (manually construct a resource). What you should have is a repository that is capable of determining what asset (drawable or whatever) corresponds to each potential value from your `content`.

Answer (score 2):

Make a Repository that can *resolve* the asset for you...

in your UI you'd do:

```
holder.imageView.setImageResource(
       myResourceRepo.getImageResourceFor(content[position].ImageSrc)
)
```

Now what you do in there, it really depends, if you really have 100 resources, you have to find a way to MAP them together, either by creating a `mapOf(Int, "img source")` (whatever that is), where `Int` is the R.drawable.xxx and `img source` is whatever is in `content[...].imageSrc` (a String?)

This is how you map/associate them together.

If you want it to be more dynamic, then store your images in "raw assets" and using the AssetManager, load the image and convert it into a Drawable at runtime. This way you get to "construct" the asset name like you did

```
var filename = "some/path/" + content[...].imageSrc

val file = assetManager.open(filename)...
val drawable = makeDrawableFrom(file)

return drawable
```

Your viewHolder will then use it as

```
val drawable = repo.getDrawableFrom(content[x].imageSrc)
holder.imageView.setImageResource(drawable)
```

(NOTE: most of these are "pseudo-code", you have to implement most of it, but it's all possible and quite simple).

If you *REALLY* want to try to load a resource dynamically... it used to be possible with something like

```
val nameOfResource = "a" + "b" + "c" //construct your "dynamic" name
val drawable = context.resources.getIdentifier(nameOfResource,
                "drawable", context.getPackageName())
```

(not sure if this still works)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your "second method" exist instead, you can reformat your first one as follows,

```
holder.imageView.setImageResource(
when (content[position].ImageSrc) {
            1 ->  R.drawable.image_1
            2 ->  R.drawable.image_2
            3 ->  R.drawable.image_3
            else ->R.drawable.image_else
        }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val imageId = resources.getIdentifier("com.packagename.app:drawable/image_${content[position].ImageSrc}", null, null);
holder.imageView.setImageResource(imageId)
```

Comment: Please try to provide explanation as to why your solution works and how its useful